# Splitting a string in 2 pieces

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example if I have

```py
x = "12345;9876"
y = ?
z = ?
```

how can i make it so y is only the part before the semicolon and z is the part after the semicolon

Comment: please study and try doing yourself instead of really basic questions, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
x = "12345;9876"

y = x.split(';')[0]

z = x.split(';')[1]

print(y)
print(z)
```

Result:

```
12345 # This is y
9876 # This is z
```

Answer (score 2):

```
y, z = x.split(';')
```

This uses two features:

- The split function (method) to split the string into two parts (or more, if there are more semicolons)
- Tuple unpacking, which lets us assign a list (or similar) to several variables, putting each item of the list into the corresponding variable

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple:

```
y, z = x.split(";")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = "12345;9876"
y, z=x.split(';')
```